# add Push Notification HTML5 based mobile application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

I've created an HTML5 based mobile application using Cordova.

And I want to send users some messages even if the application is running in the background, the funny thing is that I tough it would be easy, but it looks like I've missed something.

I've found thing related to Google Cloud Messaging and the Apple Push Notification System, but I don't want anything that fancy.

May be its obvious but I've tried using notifications from `org.apache.cordova.dialogs` plugin.

Can anybody help? a hint or a guide would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the way you want these notification be shown? On fixed time basis (alarm plugins) or by an external event call?

Comment: I would like those notifications to be shown depending on some other customised event, that could be changed by time

Comment: You should be more specific about that **customized event**. How will it be triggered? I guess serverside? Then I'd say Push is really the way to go for you, since it's built for exactly that use case.

Comment: @qefzec Yes, indeed, but I would like to have sometimes a mixed events triggered server side, and on time basis, like to notify the user "you have been missing from the application"

Comment: Concerning the time triggered notification, I just found [this cordova plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#schedule-local-notifications), it should exactly meet your needs and does not require setup of Push Services.